WCAG and use of Tables
I'm in the process of making a website ADA compliant. There's some confusion on the use of tables. The overall layout of the site should be correct with head, body, section, nav, and footer tags. Inside of the main content section, there are some tables used to list the products for sale. It's a two column, multi-row table, that lists the color of the product in the left hand column and the corresponding "add to cart" button in the right hand column.  Thoughts on ADA compliance?


              
.table.sale-table{
border: #DFDFDF solid thin;
background:#f7f7f7;
}

table.sale-table td {
border-right: #DFDFDF solid  thin;
border-bottom: #DFDFDF solid thin;
padding-top:10px;

}
<table width="98%" border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" class="sale-table">
                      <tr>
                        <td width="50%">Blue Shirt</td>
                        <td width="50%">Paypal Button</td>
                      </tr>
                       <tr>
                        <td width="50%">Red Shirt</td>
                        <td width="50%">Paypal Button</td>
                      </tr>
                       <tr>
                        <td width="50%">Yellow Shirt</td>
                        <td width="50%">Paypal Button</td>
                      </tr>
                       <tr>
                        <td width="50%">Pink Shirt</td>
                        <td width="50%">Paypal Button</td>
                      </tr>
                       <tr>
                        <td width="50%">Black Shirt</td>
                        <td width="50%">Paypal Button</td>
                      </tr>
     </table>




There is information missing to answer this question. What does the button look like? It’s very important to seize accessibility of this code snippet. The table is missing a header <thead> and header cells <th>, when navigating with the tab key, it’s important where focus goes an what accessible name the button has.
